# Logarithm Question With Square Root

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

There is a problem that I cannot solve:

> $$ \sqrt{ (\log {8})^2 + \left(\log {\frac {1}{16}}\right)^2} $$

> $$ A) \sqrt{2} \log {2}$$
> $$ B) \log {2}$$
> $$ C) 3\log {2}$$
> $$ D) 5\log {2}$$
> $$ E) 5$$

Rules for logaritm:

> $$ \log_a{b^c} = c.\log_a{b}  $$

Therefore inner of the square:

> $$ \log({2^3})^2 + \log({2^{-4}})^2 $$
> $$ \log({2^6}) + \log({2^{-8}})  $$
> $$ 6 \log({2}) -8 \log({2})  $$
> $$ -2 \log({2})  $$

Where is my error at the calculation? Thanks in advance.

Mr. Oscar Lenzi has informed me about the solution. Here is the solution: (inner of the square)

> $$ (\log{2^3})^2 + (\log{2^{-4}})^2 $$
> $$ (3\log{2})^2 + (-4 \log{2})^2 $$
> $$ 9 (\log{2})^2 + 16 (\log{2})^2 $$
> $$ 25 (\log{2})^2 $$

> $$  \sqrt{25 (\log{2})^2} $$
> $$ 5 \log{2} $$

Answer is D.

Comment: Note that $(\log8)^2\ne\log(8^2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misdid parentheses.  Properly, $(\log 8)^2=(3\log 2)^2=9[(\log 2)^2]$.  Similarly for $[\log (1/16)]^2$.  With careful use of parentheses you should get a positive radicand whose square root matches (the correct) one of the given choices.